# how is database related to tables in Base or MS access?

Tags: database, ms-access

how is database related to tables in Base or MS access, i want the answer to relation that how a database is related to tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, given the minimalistic detail in the question:

> Databases contains tables.

[Table (database)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_%28database%29)

Comment: thnks... well minimal questions have importance